# SQLAlchemy Multiple class linked to same child class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have multiple products that each, has a list of `Pricing` objects to record the historical price of those objects. I can't seemed to wrap around my head what will the relation be.

```py
class Apple:
    __tablename__ = 'Apple'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    prices= relationship("Pricing")

class Banana:
    __tablename__ = 'Banana'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    prices= relationship("Pricing")

class Pear:
    __tablename__ = 'Pear'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    prices= relationship("Pricing")
```

so basically each product (or fruit) will have a list of `Pricing` objects. The columns of PricingTable are:  `PricingDate` and `PriceValue`.

So how would I write the code for `Pricing` class? Essentially the table ought to look like this:

| id | PricingDate | PriceValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-06-01 | 2.00 |
| 2 | 2019-05-28 | 6.08 |
| 3 | 2022-04-07 | 10.42 |
| 4 | 2018-12-12 | 3.45 |
| 5 | 2014-09-08 | 9.20 |
| 6 | 2022-08-31 | 25.34 |

The Pricing table doesn't need to keep track of what fruit is for each row, as I would only access the fruits first, then retrieve it's `Pricing` records. In essence, the dictionary ought to look something like this:

```
apple_records = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'first_apple',
        'prices': [
            {
                'id': 1,
                'PricingDate': '2019-06-01',
                'PriceValue': 2.00
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'second_apple',
        'prices': [
            {
                'id': 4,
                'PricingDate': '2018-12-12',
                'PriceValue': 3.45
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In essence I wouldn't really read from the `PricingTable` directly. All I need is the all fruits will have a list of `Pricing` objects, so that CRUD comes easy and I would want SQLAlchemy to handle that for me; aka delete/update cascade etc.

Thoughts/Options that went through my head:

1. From the looks of it, it seems like I just need a one-to-many parent-child relationship.
2. But that's not the case, as I now have many, distinct types of parents (different types of fruits)
3. Do I have to create multiple association tables? Would that mean if I have 50 distinct fruits, I would need to create 50 association tables?
4. Also the number of fruits are unknown, I am going to create those classes dynamically.
5. Do I have to create multiple foriegn keys in `Pricing` table, one column for each type of fruit that exists?
6. From `c#` perspective, this is something like a class can just implement an `IPricing` interface, and multiple class can inherit/implement it, as long as they have the attributes `PricingList`

Answer (score 0):

> From the looks of it, it seems like I just need a one-to-many parent-child relationship.
> But that's not the case, as I now have many, distinct types of parents (different types of fruits)
> Do I have to create multiple association tables? Would that mean if I have 50 distinct fruits, I would need to create 50 association tables?

You are looking for [polymorphism](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance.html) in SQLAlchemy. It's a complex topic and cannot be broadly answered in the context of this question. There are multiple ways to solve this, but because the question does not discuss about the larger general problem, it is not possible to point out what would the best way.

> Also the number of fruits are unknown, I am going to create those classes dynamically.

This sounds like you are doing something wrong. Although it is possible if you need to dynamically generate Python classes you have likely a larger architectural problem with your code. Because the question does not have enough context, it is not possible to point out any better solutions.

> Do I have to create multiple foriegn keys in Pricing table, one column for each type of fruit that exists?

See polymorphism above.

> From c# perspective, this is something like a class can just implement an IPricing interface, and multiple class can inherit/implement it, as long as they have the attributes PricingList

Python has a concept of [abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) that can act as an interface, as Python supports [multiple inheritance](https://realpython.com/lessons/multiple-inheritance-python/).